# Python reduce nested loops in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My dictionary structure looks like this:

```
mapping = {'outputs': {'cube1': {'tx': 1.0}}}
```

And I am iterating them like so:

```
for node, props in mapping['outputs'].items():
    for prop, value in props.items():
        #Further loops
```

Is there an elegant way to collapse these two nested loops into one?

I would like to get this as a result:

```
for node, prop, value in nest_loop(mapping['outputs']):
    #Further loops
```

Comment: not without encapsulating the inelegance into a generator function. I'm running behind schedule right now, or I'd make an answer out of what I just said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to do the work similar to what your nested for loops is doing. Example -

```
nest_loop = ((a,b,c) for a,x in mapping['outputs'].items() for b,c in x.items())
for node, prop, value in nest_loop:
    #Do work
```

But I prefer the more readable nested loops over this.

Demo -

```
>>> mapping = {'outputs': {'cube1': {'tx': 1.0}}}
>>> nest_loop = ((a,b,c) for a,x in mapping['outputs'].items() for b,c in x.items())
>>> for node, prop, value in nest_loop:
...     print(node,prop,value)
...
cube1 tx 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason I want to collapse these two is that I have more loops inside.

Comment: At the moment I have exactly the same generator expression as a solution in my code, but I am still open to more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want:

`for node, prop, value in [(node, prop, value) for node, props in mapping["outputs"].items() for prop, value in props.items()]:
  print node, prop, value`